# How can I use the edit_post function in PyTumblr?

Tags: python, tumblr, function-parameter

I am trying to edit some posts in my tumblr blog using [PyTumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/) and the [edit_post function](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/blob/master/pytumblr/__init__.py), but I can't figure out exactly what parameters are needed. I try to put the tags parameter but it's not accepted.

I have tried this:

```
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                   OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
client.edit_post('nameofblog', {'id': 39228373})
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: edit_post() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any ideas?

This is the function:

```
    def edit_post(self, blogname, **kwargs):
            """
    Edits a post with a given id

    :param blogname: a string, the url of the blog you want to edit
    :param tags: a list of tags that you want applied to the post
    :param tweet: a string, the customized tweet that you want
    :param date: a string, the GMT date and time of the post
    :param format: a string, sets the format type of the post. html or markdown
    :param slug: a string, a short text summary to the end of the post url

    :returns: a dict created from the JSON response
    """
      url = "/v2/blog/%s/post/edit" % blogname
      return self.send_api_request('post', url, kwargs)
```

Comment: Exactly what did you try to pass as a parameter (& it didn't work)?

Comment: First of all, I don't see where do I put the id of the post I want.

Answer (score 3):

The PyTumblr library offers a thin layer over the [Tumblr REST API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2), and all arguments apart from the blog name should be passed in as keyword arguments.

The `TumblrRestClient.edit_post()` method, then, acts as a proxy for the [`/post/edit` endpoint](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#editing), and it takes all the same parameters.

As such, you'd call it like:

```
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                               OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
client.edit_post('nameofblog', id=39228373)
```

That is not to say that if you have a dictionary object with post details, you cannot make use of that.

If you wanted to set the title of a given post id, you could use:

```
post = {'id': 39228373, 'title': 'New title!'}
client.edit_post('nameofblog', **post)
```

Here the `post` dictionary is being applied to the `.edit_post()` method call as separate keyword arguments using the `**` syntax. Python then takes each key-value pair in the input dictionary and applies that pair as a keyword argument.

You should be able to set any of the parameters applicable to your post type, listed under the [posting documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting).

The problem then, is that the `.edit_post()` method leaves the `valid_params` argument to `self. send_api_request()` to the default empty list, leading to a guaranteed validation exception for *anything* you pass in. This *must* be a bug, and I [commented on Mike's issue](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/issues/29) to point this out to the developer.

Comment: Got the bounty for the detailed explanation of using arguments in a function.

Comment: Great answer and worthy of the bounty! Also learned something, which is a bonus.

Comment: @mikedidthis: TBH I am feeling guilty for having missed the validation problem here. I skipped straight over `if not params` in the validation function assuming that there'd be an early return for an empty list of valid parameter names too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well don't. OP got a question well answered and the issue has been reported. Side note, Boba hat looks amazing! :D

Answer (score 1):

Passing an ID is not well documented, so I asked:

```
client.edit_post("nameofblog", id=39228373, other="details", tags=["are", "cool"])
```

Ref: http://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/issues/29

Comment: The above gives me this error:
Exception: id are not allowed fields

Comment: @evil_inside I have updated my answer based on a response from the owner.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned function edit_post, relies on the following function:

```
def send_api_request(self, method, url, params={}, valid_parameters=[], needs_api_key=False):
        """
Sends the url with parameters to the requested url, validating them
to make sure that they are what we expect to have passed to us

:param method: a string, the request method you want to make
:param params: a dict, the parameters used for the API request
:param valid_parameters: a list, the list of valid parameters
:param needs_api_key: a boolean, whether or not your request needs an api key injected

:returns: a dict parsed from the JSON response
"""
        if needs_api_key:
            params.update({'api_key': self.request.consumer.key})
            valid_parameters.append('api_key')

        files = []
        if 'data' in params:
            if isinstance(params['data'], list):
                files = [('data['+str(idx)+']', data, open(data, 'rb').read()) for idx, data in enumerate(params['data'])]
            else:
                files = [('data', params['data'], open(params['data'], 'rb').read())]
            del params['data']

        validate_params(valid_parameters, params)
        if method == "get":
            return self.request.get(url, params)
        else:
            return self.request.post(url, params, files)
```

So, the problem is that the edit_post function in the following line :

```
return self.send_api_request('post', url, kwargs)
```

does not provide the choice for valid options, as does this function in the last line:

```
def reblog(self, blogname, **kwargs):
        """
Creates a reblog on the given blogname

:param blogname: a string, the url of the blog you want to reblog to
:param id: an int, the post id that you are reblogging
:param reblog_key: a string, the reblog key of the post

:returns: a dict created from the JSON response
"""
        url = "/v2/blog/%s/post/reblog" % blogname

        valid_options = ['id', 'reblog_key', 'comment', 'type', 'state', 'tags', 'tweet', 'date', 'format', 'slug']
        if 'tags' in kwargs:
            # Take a list of tags and make them acceptable for upload
            kwargs['tags'] = ",".join(kwargs['tags'])
        return self.send_api_request('post', url, kwargs, valid_options)
```

To fix it, I modified the return line to :

```
send_api_request('post', url, {'id':post_id, 'tags':tags}, ['id', 'tags']
```

I added just the tags I wanted. It should work with others too.

Comment: Ah! I missed the part where an empty list if valid parameters *still* leads to parameters being validated. That *must* be a bug; I've comment on the issue mike opened.